# Can fluent API set NotMapped on all entities that inherit from a base class?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Sometimes it's useful to derive my entities from a base class like this:

```
public abstract class DestructableBase : IDestructable
{
   /// <summary>
   /// If true, this object should be deleted from the database.
   /// </summary>
   [NotMapped]
   public bool _destroy { get; set; }
}
```

This allows a web client to mark an entity as needing to be deleted when data is posted back to the server. Obviously I do not wish to record such a property in the database though, so I use the [NotMapped] attribute.

I've begun using the fluent API more and more to do my configurations though and would like to stop using data annotations. Is there a way to use the fluent API to do this without having to set Ignore() on every entity individually? Or is there a better way altogether?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to use this class as a base class for your entity configurations:

```
public class DestructableBaseConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : DestructableBase
{
    public DestructableEntityConfiguration()
    {
        Ignore(e => e._destroy);
    }
}
```

Now every other entity derived from `DestructableBase` needs entity configuration class derived from `DestructableBaseConfiguration`. You will register your configurations to `modelBuilder` in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: Yeah, that may be the thing to do. Thank you.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: What if we wanted to ignore the base class completely? Is there a way to do that in EF 5.0 CF?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: In such case you must not map the base class and EF will ignore it. You also must not use `DbSet` of the base class.